# Efficient way to create thousands of hyperlinks using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA question for creating hyperlinks for a range of cells.

In my application, I have a table of data where one column lists IDs that I would like to add hyperlinks to to open a corresponding report/page for that ID.

In all the following cases assume all the cells are populated with numeric IDs.

I am currently using code very similar to the following (simplified for this example):

```
Dim r As Range, c As Range
Set r = Range("C1:C60000")
For Each c In r
   ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.add anchor:=c, address:="http://www.url.com?address=" &  c.value
Next c
```

However, as the range gets larger - the time for this code to execute gets exceedingly longer. In the case where the URL is always the same the following code runs quite quickly.

```
 Dim r as Range
 set r = Range("A1:A60000")
 r.Hyperlinks.add anchor:=r, address:="http://www.url.com"
```

My question is when the URLs are different, specifically if they incorporate data from the cell there is there a way that is more efficient than what I'm currently doing.

Any help or insight would be appreciated. 
Thank you,

Example Data (in an CSV format and as an Excel Table screenshot), I need to be able to add hyperlinks to the entire fist column in the format of "http://www.urltest.com/sample?id=[ID]" where [ID] is the value from the cell.

- Number,Assignee,Title
- 383087,Me,Fix this problem
- 403749,You,A problem with the compiler
- 403856,You,An issue with the monitor
- 440912,Me,Three things to fix first
- 458523,Another Person,"You, me, and this problem"
- 476182,You,A star in the sky
- 485834,You,Three little bears
- 499569,You,My keyboard doesn't work
- 500552,Me,My mouse doesn't work
- 516824,Me,I can't log in
- 523654,Another Person,Too many computer cables
- 536632,Someone Else,I have an issue with PHP
- 556012,Me,I have an issue with VBA
- 561275,You,I have two issues with C++
- 569014,Me,My Perl script doesn't work
- 572658,You,JavaScript is giving me a headache
- 667911,Me,My headphones are disconnected
- 704432,Me,I need a software upgrade
- 721637,Me,My laptop is too slow
- 735784,Me,Your server is rejecting my connection
- 765477,Me,I don't know what Port to connect to
- 778808,Me,There is something wrong with my XML
- 788865,Me,The power to my computer keeps fluctating
- 791957,Me,My power bar needs to be replaced
- 793507,Me,This is a must before we release the product
- 794067,Me,There two products do not work well together
- 798445,Me,These things take time

[image: Example Table]

Answer (score 5):

Fastest way I can think of is using the `HYPERLINK` Function and assign the values to all cells in one go :) This will also **ENSURE** that you will **NOT** have to loop.

The syntax of Hyperlink is

***HYPERLINK(link_location, [friendly_name])***

Read about it in Excel help or Google it.

The `ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))` give you the address of the current cell.

Try this

```
Sub test_simple_diffurl()
    Dim r As Range

    Set r = Range("C1:C60000")

    r.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""http://www.url.com?address="" & ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),""Test with "" & ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))"
End Sub
```

Comment: I've never seen a formula added in that way, thank you - very quick. My example was a bit generic - the actual application is on a table column of ID values, where each ID value should have a link to a website that looks up the corresponding report. With this method I assume I'd need to keep the values in a separate (hidden column) to use them in the formula.

Comment: `My example was a bit generic` First and very Important rule in Stackoverflow: Never waste anyone's time... Including yours :) Now please amend your question and ask a realistic question...

Comment: kool :) May I see sample data... say for 10 rows? You can upload a screenshot. So that I can test the code before posting?

Comment: Hi @Siddharth-rout, I finally got a chance to put together a set of sample data. In reality the table would be hundreds of rows longer.